# Added EOS to MyEtherWwallet as default token

Tags: myetherwallet

I've added EOS to MyEtherWallet as default token. How do I correct this? It tells me to load tokens but it isn't in the list. The contract is fine and tokens are present, just elusive and misnamed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check your balance by pasting your address into a block explorer site like https://ethplorer.io/